# Draw an animated line between two markers in MapBox

Tags: line, mapbox, animated

I'm new to mapbox 
I import some markers from a csv file, and i can draw lines between them manually , from each port to its destination.
for example from Morocco to China, but if i show you my map, you can't know where is the Port and what is the Destination : from Morocco to China or the reverse. so, for this reason i would like draw an animated line from each port to its destination.
For the moment i don't have any code, i found in the below link how to draw an animated line but i couldn't do it between to markers, because they talk about a sinusoidal function. 
https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/dynamically-drawing-a-line/
Can you help me please ? 
Thank you !

Comment: Ok, what did your research turn up? What have you tried? What didn't work? What problems did it give? Any errors? This is by far not a question which adheres to Stackoverflow standards. Please give this a good and thorough read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and afterwards edit your question.

Comment: Thank you for your response, next time i will try to ask a good question, it is my first, that's why !
I have many questions, i'm starting with this : 
Ok, i import some markers from a csv file, and i can draw lines between them, from each port to its destination.
but if you see the map, you don't know the direction from A to B or the reverse.
so, for this reason i would like draw a animated direction from each port to its destination.
for the moment i don't have any code.

Comment: Please edit your question, add that to your question and add what you've researched, and what you found etc.

Answer (score 3):

In the example you linked, you can change the `add()` function to start drawing at your first point and stop drawing at your last. Ideally your markers are in the order you want the line to be drawn:

```
// add your points
var points = [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [0, 0]
        },
        "properties": {}
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [10, -10]
        },
        "properties": {}
    },
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [50, 50]
        },
        "properties": {}
    }
]

// add a variable for keeping track of points
var y = 0; 

// Start drawing the polyline.
add();

function add() {

    // add a point on the line for the new marker
    polyline.addLatLng(
        L.latLng(points[y].geometry.coordinates[1],
            points[y].geometry.coordinates[0])
    );


    // Pan the map along with where the line is being added.
    map.setView(points[y].geometry.coordinates, 3);

    // Continue to draw and pan the map by calling `add()`
    // until `y` reaches the number of points
    if (++y < points.length) window.setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
```